# How do I delete the "General" link on my header? (Shows up next to the icon and site name)

Tags: header, item-deleted

I'm building a SharePoint site, and it was requested that I get rid of "general" that takes you to MSFT general page of how to use SharePoint, etc.
Would anyone happen to know how I may get rid of this? I've checked settings>site contents>Edit links. Nada.
[image: Header Image with General]